# How to combine a separate thead and tbody into one table using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, html-table, row

I'm currently working on a project in which I need to dynamically generate a table. Each time the table generates it will be different, since I am making a different API call to different endpoints.

The purpose of this table is to show which students are in each particular class. As of now, I am able to get this information, make a separate thead, and append it to a div called "tableContainer". The rest of the table, the tbody, is generated separately and appended to the same div.

Here's what I have so far:

```
let createStudentTable = (data) => {
let tableHeader = ('<table class=\'table\'><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Major</th></tr></thead></table>');

$("#tableContainer").append(tableHeader);
```

//then I loop through the data and generate the tbody based on how many people are in the class

```
for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
let tableRow = ('<table class=\'table\'><tbody class=\'tbody\'><tr><td>' + data.name + '</td><td>' + data.age + '</td><td>' + data.major + '</td></tr></tbody></table>');

$("#tableContainer).append(tableRow);

}
}
```

So the table will be different depending on how many students are in the class.

My problem -- I want to use a jQuery plugin called tablesorter that sorts the rows by thead and tbody, but everything must be in the same table. But right now, the tableHeader and the tables generated by the student are their own table. How can I 'mash' all of them together to create one big table?

Comment: You probably do not need to generate thead and table (just put it directly to html) only tbody. Try to generate and insert it in existed table.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so if we have a look at your code, every time you loop through the array you are creating a whole new table, instead, why not initialise the table in your html, and append the rows?

inside #tableContainer have

```
<table id="studentTable" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Name </th>
      <th> Age </th>
      <th> Major </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

then in your loop instead of doing a whole row and appending to the div, append to the table itself

```
let tableRows = '<tbody>';
for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
    tableRows += ('<tr><td>' + data.name + '</td><td>' + data.age + '</td><td>' + data.major + '</td></tr>');
}
tableRows += '</tbody>';
$("#studentTable").append(tableRows);
```

If the table needs to be built 100% with JS, then we can do that too

```
let tableShell = '<table id=\'studentTable\' class=\'table\'><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Major</th></tr></thead>';

$('#tableContainer').append(tableShell);

let tableRows = '<tbody>';
for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
    tableRows += ('<tr><td>' + data.name + '</td><td>' + data.age + '</td><td>' + data.major + '</td></tr>');
}
tableRows += '</tbody>';
$("#studentTable").append(tableRows);
```